# What is "很秋" means?

Tags: traditional-characters

I use google translation, but it says "very autumn" ?

Sounds wired...

I think it might be describe something for how it feels like.

Because it use "很", it means very in Chinese

Example, 最近那个小李，得了第一名，很秋

Comment: It's not normal Chinese. Where did you see the example sentence from?

Comment: @Betty Just for example, when I saw somebody write it on the Internet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Taiwanese dialect. If you are fluent in Chinese, just read the link in the reference.  If not, I'll paraphrase as follows.

秋 in Taiwan can mean 嚣张, which here should be taken as having too much pride, exaggerated pride, or simply being arrogant, or in an overbearing manner.  Thus your example sentence can be translated into English as "That Buddy Li got the first place recently and was very arrogant now."

---

[獨／台語很「秋」在新加坡是別的含義](https://tw.news.yahoo.com/%E7%8D%A8-%E5%8F%B0%E8%AA%9E%E5%BE%88-%E7%A7%8B-%E5%9C%A8%E6%96%B0%E5%8A%A0%E5%9D%A1%E6%98%AF%E5%88%A5%E7%9A%84%E5%90%AB%E7%BE%A9-011003610.html)

Comment: What would the correct character for「秋」be here? For either “arrogant” or “pretty”? Would it just be「鬚」? I think it may work for arrogant as an extension of:「聳鬚」- but 「鬚」for pretty...? Not sure.

Comment: Give you two references. 1. 唱秋 (arrogant) <https://www.facebook.com/OhTaigiTW/posts/171812020954625>  2. 起秋 (erection) <https://www.facebook.com/groups/enjoyfonts/posts/1723021111186090/> These URLs provides correct words of 秋 but most people don't use it since they are not common characters and not in textbooks. (The total number of traditional Chinese characters is 50k ~ 80k.) More importantly these two 秋 sounds very very alike and it was not elegant to pronounce it in my childhood.